# Dynamical systems proofs wanted

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, alternative-proof

Recently I read **dynamical systems proofs** of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ and Fermat's theorem. Now, I'm interested in other dynamical systems proofs of well-known things similar to this. What book, journal or notes should I read, do you have any suggestion?

**What is your favorite proof done in dynamical system way?**

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide references to those dynamical systems proofs you recently read? I am curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My favorite dynamical system proof is that almost every $x \in [0,1]$ is normal base $2$. That is, if $x = .a_1a_2\dots$ in binary expansion (which is unique for all $x$ except a measure $0$ set), then $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\#\{n \le N : a_n = 1\}}{N} = \frac{1}{2}.$$ The proof is to consider the map $T: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ given by $Tx = 2x \pmod{1}$ and $f(x) = \lfloor 2x \rfloor$. Then $a_1 = f(x), a_2 = f(Tx), a_3 = f(T^2x)$, etc. One can check that $T$ is ergodic w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. Then, by the pointwise ergodic theorem, for a.e. $x \in [0,1]$, $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} f(T^nx) = \int_0^1 f(x)dx = \frac{1}{2}$. This easily generalizes to all other bases $b$ (with $f(x) := 1_{\{j\}}(\lfloor bx \rfloor)$ giving that the digit $j$ occurs a proportion $\frac{j}{b}$ of the time).

Answer (score 4):

I'll prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, as @Sunghyuk Park requested. Proof of Fermat's theorem I read [here.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/facf/da78f07decc4483a17189731b071df888f0c.pdf)

I'll assume that notion of orbit is known. 
$T(x)=(\sqrt{2}-1)x$ has orbit

$O(x_0) = \{(\sqrt{2}-1)^n x_0 :n\in\{0\}\cup\mathbb{N}\}$.

Orbit converges to zero since $0<\sqrt{2}-1<1$. Let us assume that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational and equal to $\frac{p}{q}$ for $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$. It is easy to check that $\sqrt{2}^n q$ is natural number.

By using binomial theorem, we get

$0<(\sqrt{2}-1)^nq =\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\sqrt{2}^k(-1)^{n-k}q\in\mathbb{Z}$

from where we get $O(q)\subset\mathbb{N}$, which contradicts the fact that sequence converges to zero.

Comment: Why is $\sqrt{2}^nq$ a natural number? With the assumption above, $\sqrt{2}^nq = \dfrac{p^n}{q^{n-1}}$. If this is natural for all $n$, first we have all primes in the factoriztion of $q$ into primes also appear in $p$. Let us consider one of them and call it $r$. Then if $r$ appears $a$ times in $p$ and $b$ times in $q$ then we must have $(n-1)b \le na$ for all $n$. Letting $n\rightarrow \infty$ implies that $1 \le \dfrac{a}{b}$. That is $b \le a$. As $r$ was arbitrary, this implies that $q|p$. So, is the assumption saying suppose $\sqrt{2}$ is an integer? (Does my argument have an error?)